# localization issues in windows

Tags: windows, php, localization

I have this question in stackoverflow which is about getting incorrect date in php:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4771775/cannot-get-the-correct-date-and-time-in-php

Someone said that its localization issues.
I have tried the script on my friend's computer. And the time is displayed correctly. I cannot move on with my project which needs to have the correct time if I can't solve this soon. What can you recommend?

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the timezone function correctly? Which PHP version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I think this points to a PHP issue. At any rate, your `date_default_timezone_set` call isn't interpreted, otherwise you'd get the proper time zone. Since date_default_timezone_set is PHP 5-only, I guess your friend is running a PHP 5 interpreter, while you're running the script through PHP 4. Try inserting `echo (phpversion());` and see what it says.

Comment: I'm running 5.3.0

Comment: And phpversion() returns that?

Comment: not exactly, it just said: 5.3.0

Comment: Okay, something else: What does PHP return on date_default_timezone_get()?

Comment: you mean echo it? it returns 1

Comment: Really? Did you really echo date_.... GET or did you echo SET? I need GET, it return the value set for your timezone. Just copy echo(date_default_timezone_get()); after your date_default_set(...). Then run it once with the ..set call commented out and once not commented out. What does it echo in each case?